# Getting Invalid maximum heap size while running java server

Tags: java, jvm

Getting this error while trying to run Java server in my local environment:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Java Service Wrapper Professional Edition 64-bit 3.5.29
  Copyright (C) 1999-2016 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
    http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
  Licensed to SAP SE for hybris Platform

Launching a JVM...
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx${tomcat.maxSize}
JVM exited while loading the application.
Reloading Wrapper configuration...
Launching a JVM...
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx${tomcat.maxSize}
JVM exited while loading the application.
Reloading Wrapper configuration...
Launching a JVM...
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx${tomcat.maxSize}
JVM exited while loading the application.
Reloading Wrapper configuration...
Launching a JVM...
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx${tomcat.maxSize}
JVM exited while loading the application.
Reloading Wrapper configuration...
Launching a JVM...
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx${tomcat.maxSize}
JVM exited while loading the application.
There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
  There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

And this is the bat file which is running the Java server:

```
@echo off

setlocal

SET MODE=%1

IF  "%MODE%" == "" (
    SET MODE=run
)

IF "%1"=="debug" (
    SET _YWRAPPER_CONF=%~dp0tomcat/conf/wrapper-debug.conf
    SET MODE=run
)

IF "%1"=="minimal" (
    SET _YWRAPPER_CONF=%~dp0tomcat/conf/wrapper-minimal.conf
    SET MODE=run
)

IF "%1"=="jprofiler" (
    SET _YWRAPPER_CONF=%~dp0tomcat/conf/wrapper-jprofiler.conf
    SET MODE=run
)

IF "%1"=="" (
   set _YWRAPPER_CONF=%~dp0tomcat/conf/wrapper.conf
) 

IF "%1"=="-v" (
    call java -cp %~dps0tomcat\lib\catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
    GOTO:EOF
)

call %~dps0tomcat\bin\catalina.bat %MODE%

endlocal
```

What could be the reason and how can I solve this issue ?

I tried to restart my machine, and it didn't fix it, also tried to run with -Xmx value and no success either.

Comment: It looks like you are using a wrapper script, and the script is not expanding some variables correctly.  But there is insufficient information to easily identify the cause.

Comment: @StephenC I updated the question, please have a look

Comment: How does your `wrapper.conf` look like? Note that the syntax for expanding environment variables in wrapper.conf is `%tomcat.maxSize%`, not `${tomcat.maxSize}`